# Javascript (or angular) point variable to local file (json)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to used locally stored json files to pull in information, right now I am just hardcoding the json in a variable, but what I would like to do is point to some json files I have locally

something like -

```
var myData = "scripts/data/myData.json";
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to make an AJAX request to your JSON File. Are you using AngularJS?

Comment: @nanndoj Angular - would prefer not to use jquery for now.

Comment: AJAX doesn't mean its jquery, ajax can be referring anything thats asynchronous call.  And yes you have to use a $http call to get it because web javascript cant load files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in this way :

```
 $http.get("scripts/data/myData.json").success(function(response) {    

            $scope.myData= response

     }).error(function(err) {       

        alert(err);

 })
```

Please see here working demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/dV1lHIZyoKYNDxbPwHNV?p=preview

Comment: OP, keep in mind that if you are developing locally without a web server (IE your URL begins with file:///), AJAX will likely not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I`m pretty sure that you can not make AJAX request to a file:// protocol.